# GTK+, Windows, Code::Blocks, C

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks, gtk+, msys2

Пытаюсь разобраться с установкой **GTK+** под **Windows**, хочу использовать **GTK+** в **Code::Blocks** с компилятором **MinGW-w64**. Но не получается. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

1) Установил **msys2** и выполнил все необходимые команды, которые указаны тут:

```
https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php
```

2) Установил **MinGW-w64** с **sourceforge**;

3) Подключил **MinGW-w64** к **Code::Blocks**, проверил запуском консольного приложения, компилятор работает;

4) Делаю в **Code::Blocks** проект **GTK+**, указав путь к папке с **GTK+**, как:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64
```

Я ведь правильно понимаю, что данная папка - это все необходимые ресурсы **GTK+** для использования с компилятором **MinGW-w64**?

Тестовый проект **GTK+** собирается в **Code::Blocks** без единой ошибки, но при попытке запустить саму программу в дебагере, в релизе или просто из папки с проектом, - происходит несколько ошибок, типа:

```
Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll.

Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует libgobject-2.0-0.dll. 

Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует libglib-2.0-0.dll.
```

Я не понимаю, что надо этому **exe**-шнику. На другом ПК делал все то же самое, в недалеком прошлом, и там программа-пример собирается и запускается в дебагере/релизе, не ругаясь на отсутствие **dll**-ок.

Я уже раз десять переустановив **msys2**, вновь выполнив все команды для установки окружения и зависимостей для **GTK+**.

Не помогло.

А каждый раз руками расфасовывать библиотеки по папкам - вариант неприемлемый. Хотелось бы разобраться, в чем проблема, ведь ее, очевидно, быть не должно.

Comment: скорее всего на другой машине было установлено что-то, что уже установило эти библиотеки (например, gimp) и они были в C:\Windows скопированы. И все работало. Но можно попробовать сделать статическую линковку. В этом случае может и выйдет

Comment: Дело точно не в этом.

Comment: Уверены? Возможно, на другой машине компилятор был добавлен в PATH, и рядом с ним лежали эти библиотеки. Но на самом деле не так важно, почему на другой машине работало без .dll. Если вы хотите, чтобы у обычных пользователей ваша программа работала, придется все эти .dll хранить в папке с экзешником, это совершенно нормально. Или линковать статически.

Comment: У вас шаг №2 лишний. MinGW-w64 со всеми библиотеками устанавливается **внутри** msys2 (командами `pacman -S ...`). Вот именно ту версию mingw и надо добавлять в CodeBlocks.

Comment: @zed, понял, спасибо!

Comment: Но теперь другая проблема - при открытии exe просит кучу dll-ок. Сначала он просил 4 штуки. Я их нашел и дал ему. После этого он запросил другие, еще штук 5. Повтор, ему снова нужны dll, еще какие-то. Как решается вопрос с распространением приложения GTK+? Может есть какой-то флаг компиляции, чтобы все требуемые библиотеки зашились в exe?

Comment: Вот тут что-то про это есть: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875855/statically-linking-gtk-libraries-in-windows

Comment: Да, собрать все необходимые dll в кучу может быть не так и просто. И на сколько я знаю, нету стандартных средств/утилит чтобы сделать это. Но есть самописные утилиты, при помощи которых можно автоматом  собрать все dll: [mingw-bundledlls](https://github.com/mpreisler/mingw-bundledlls) (написано на python), [pe-util](https://github.com/gsauthof/pe-util) (c++ && boost).

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо!